# Issue with query for search bar

Tags: php, mysql

I've built a simple search bar for my website, and if my query looks like this, it works great:

```
$sql = query("SELECT id, firstname, lastname, username, location FROM 
users WHERE firstname LIKE '%" . $search_query . "%' LIMIT 20");
```

but if i write it like that, it echoes a SQL Syntax error :

```
$sql = query("SELECT id, firstname, lastname, username, location FROM 
users WHERE firstname, lastname, username, location  LIKE '%" . $search_query . "%'   
LIMIT 20");
```

The difference between the 2 queries is that the 2nd one will **search through multiple columns which is what i need since my users can search either for a name or a city.**

How should I re-write it ?

Comment: You need a `LIKE` for each column and `OR` them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify each column's search condition separately:

```
$sql = query("SELECT id, firstname, lastname, username, location
FROM users
WHERE firstname LIKE '%$search_query%'
OR lastname LIKE '%$search_query%'
OR username LIKE '%$search_query%'
OR location LIKE '%$search_query%'
LIMIT 20");
```

As you can see, I've removed the concatenation - since you're using double quotes, variables can go directly into the query.

Also, I hope `$search_query` has been santised, or you're opening yourself upto SQL injection attacks; really, you should be using parameterised queries by now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to repeat the LIKE statement for each field, unfortunately.

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, username, location FROM users 
WHERE firstname LIKE '%" . $search_query . "%'
OR lastname LIKE '%" . $search_query . "%' 
OR username LIKE '%" . $search_query . "%'
OR location LIKE '%" . $search_query . "%'
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `LIKE` does not work like that.  Try this:

```
$like_string = "'%$search_query%'";

$query = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, username, location
FROM users
WHERE firstname LIKE $like_string OR
lastname LIKE $like_string OR
username LIKE $like_string OR
location LIKE $like_string
LIMIT 20";

$sql = query($query);
```

As others will tell you, it is smart to account for SQL injection and perform sanity and validity checks before accepting any user data.  Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) question on how to prevent SQL injection.

The [PDO extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) or the [mysqli extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) is preferred for MySQL and `mysql_` functions have been deprecated (as can be seen throughout the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)).